# KeyError at /x/x/ 'pk' django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-urls

I'm trying to get a DetailView's model's pk in a variable in the get_context_data but I keep getting the error KeyError at /x/x/ 'pk'.

views.py

```
class MangaView(DetailView):
    model = Manga
    template_name = 'mangas/manga.html'
    context_object_name = 'manga'
    slug_field = 'manga_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'manga_slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        manga = get_object_or_404(Manga, id=self.kwargs['pk'])  # error line
        favorited = False
        latered = False
        ...
        return data
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mangas/', MangasHomeView.as_view(), name='mangas-home'),
    path('manga/<slug:manga_slug>/', MangaView.as_view(), name='manga'),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is caused by trying to access the `pk` value through `self.kwargs`, when in fact your view is using a `slug` field and slug URL parameter.

Try to use `self.get_object()` as it gives you current instance in `DetailView` whether it is `pk` or `slug` so:

```py
class MangaView(DetailView):
    model = Manga
    template_name = 'mangas/manga.html'
    context_object_name = 'manga'
    slug_field = 'manga_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'manga_slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        manga = self.get_object()
        favorited = False
        latered = False
        ...
        return data
```